# How to programatically get Channel and Version of Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chromium

Through the chrome UI i can access the chrome version and channel as given in [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/339573/how-can-i-tell-which-google-chrome-channel-im-running)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go through registry to find the version and channel of Chrome because that's where Chrome or Chromium will store those data. Assuming Chrome is installed for all the users, version and channel data should be located here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Google\Update\ClientState\{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}
```

If it's just installed for a single user then you should navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead. `{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}` is the GUID assigned to Chrome.

To find the version number, you should read the value of `pv`. To find the channel (stable, beta, alpha), you should read the value of `ap` and parse that string.

Current values from my machine:

```
pv: 73.0.3683.103
ap: x64-stable-statsdef_1
```